# Multiple choice question for a linear system $Ax = b$ having solution for all $b\in \mathbb{R}^m$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

I am trying to solve the following question:

Let $A$ be a $m\times n$ matrix with rank $r$. If the linear system $Ax = b$ has a solution for all $b\in \mathbb{R}^m$ then I have to check that which of the following statements are true

> > $(1)$ $ m = r$
> > $(2)$ The column space of $A$ is a proper subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$
> > $(3)$ The null space of $A$ is a non-trivial subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, whenever $m = n$.
> > $(4)$ $m \geq n$ implies $m = n$

**My approach:** If the linear system $Ax = b$ has a solution for all $b\in \mathbb{R}^m$ then for any choice of $b$ there is $x$ such that $Ax = b$ then corresponding linear transformation $T$ must be onto hence rank $T = dim \mathbb{R}^m = m$. Hence option $1$  is true. Further $rank A = m$ implies that $n \geq m$ and if $m \geq n$ then $m = n$ hence option $(4)$ is true. However I am not sure about options $2$ and $3$. Kindly help me out in solving this. If there is any other approach for example counter examples to discard the options then kindly suggest me.

Thank you so much

Comment: What does the column space have to do with solving $Ax=b$? And what does rank have to do with the dimension of the nullspace?

Comment: @TedShifrin If the solution exists $b$ must be in the column space of $A$. Thanks for comment.

Comment: Sounds like you have it all :) You can write up an answer yourself if you would like.

Comment: @TedShifrin Can we say that in this situation Matrix A must have pivot in each row and hence Rank of A must be $m$.  Thanks sir for your reply

Comment: @TedShifrin option 2 is wrong as in such case for some b there will be no $x$ such that $Ax = b$. Am i right sir?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. :)